# How to implement a real estate recommendation engine?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am talking about something like movie/item recommendation, but it seems that real estate is more tricky. When visiting a web-site and doing some search for RE, the user should be presented with some suggestions. Let's separate the task in two tasks:

a) the user has still not entered any personal info - item based recommendation
b) the user has already entered his/hers details such as income, location, etc. - item/user based recommendation

The first thing that comes to my mind for task a) is to start modeling RE features, but using some ranges instead of exact values. For example:

1. Area in m2

   - 40 - 50 we can mark it for "1"
   - 50 - 70 is "2"
   - etc ...
2. Price:

   - 20 - 30 thousands € will be marked as 1
   - 30 - 40 will be 2
   - etc ...
3. Proximity to city center:

   - 1 for the RE being within the city center
   - 2 for Zone 2 or up to 2/3 kilometers from center
   - 3 for Zone 3 or 7 kilometers from center

So having ranges lets us assign a vector to each RE property which will allows us to use: Euclidean distance, Pearson correlation and some nearest neighbor algorithms.

Please comment on my approach or suggest a new one.

Comment: Why are you using arbitrary cardinal labels for the classes? It would seem to me that you could use trunc(area/20) and trunc(income/10000) for a more general, and somehow more natural, mapping. Forcing the distance from the center to a mathematical formula seems less intuitive, although I suppose it could be done.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a website with enough traffic, you can try a pure collaborative filtering approach, i.e people who viewed this property also viewed these other properties. You could use the Pearson correlation there for good results.

Similarity between 2 RE can be defined as

```
      number of people who viewed both RE1 and RE2
sim = ---------------------------------------------
      number of people who viewed either 1 or both
```

When a user is viewing property RE you can sort all other RE properties based on the similarity score with the property being shown and show the top few.

You could add some obvious filters on top of this like the location of the property, the price range etc.

You can also define the similarity as you have suggested and mix the results from both for good representation from new RE entries which do not have a high chance of getting in if a pure collaborative filtering algorithm is used.